# How can I add a checkbox to take off a certain percentage without the use of a coupon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a client who teaches tennis lessons and would like to add a feature that allows a customer to check a box if a student is under 14 and it takes 15% off of the product price. Can anyone instruct me on how to do this? [Here](http://www.yourcourttennis.com/shop/shop-2/schedule-an-appointment/) is the way that I have implemented it, but would like it to be more simple. I am using gravity forms.

Comment: is there actual code you need help with? What you need is javascript and there are lots of tutorials that will help you. I might just say if you have a client and they are paying you, you should probably code yourself rather than using a builder, they never end up working 100%. (look at http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://www.yourcourttennis.com/shop/shop-2/schedule-an-appointment/)

Comment: Thank you for the input. The link didn't work. As for the builder, the client wanted to use Wordpress and plugins so that "they" can update...

Comment: all the link was a tester for different devices, the page is not responsive to mobiles etc.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You can't. 

Long Answer: You can, but it will be extremely exploitable. "Customers" could edit the JavaScript of the page and get free discounts! A better design choice would be to add the discounts *before* the page loads.

Comment: i dont agree, its common to add the discounts visually with js (even without js someone can edit the html) and verify that they should have gotten a discount on form submit as part of the verification.